# Script (java) convertir .geojson a jpg o png

Tags: java, img

¿alguien tiene o sabe código java que convierta un archivo .geojson en un archivo de imagen ya sea jpg o png?
Mi compañero y yo llevamos un rato intentando buscar como hacerlo y no conseguimos nada y por internet tampoco aparece gran cosa.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Tu pregunta, al parecer, [está respondida](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245875/convert-geojson-to-png) en [gis.se].